# How to write while loop with responseInputStream.read in kotlin android - - while ((i = responseInputStream.read(byteContainer))

Tags: android, kotlin, inputstream

How to use while loop with responseInputStream.read in kotlin android

[image: my code for while loop in kotlin android]

[image: another one]

here added responseInputStream read while loop .kt

```
                val responseInputStream = conn.inputStream
                val responseStringBuffer = StringBuffer()
                val byteContainer = ByteArray(1024)
                var i: Int
                while ((i = responseInputStream.read(byteContainer)) != -1) {
                    responseStringBuffer.append(String(byteContainer, 0, i))
                }
                Log.w("TAG", "res :" + responseStringBuffer.toString())
```

Comment: Instead of pictures, copy and paste your code here.

Comment: code added @AlfMoh

Comment: Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39099474/3144601

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kotlin don't like as java, you can't composing multi-expression in a single line. you should break one-line expressions into multi-lines, for example:

```
while(true){
  val i= responseInputStream.read(byteContainer);

  if(i==-1) break;

  responseStringBuffer.append(String(byteContainer, 0, i))
}
```